# How to select one row from a table and sum another table

Tags: oracle

I have this minimal example in Oracle DB

```
create table a (name varchar2(10));
create table b (x number, y number);
```

and I wish to do this

```
select (select name from a where rownum <=1), sum(x) from b;
```

but I get

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

How can I get the result I want, that is, name from table a and sum from b?

*Edit (add example)*

**Table A**

```
name
=====
foo
bar
```

**Table B**

```
x    y
=======
1    2
10   20
```

Should give

```
foo 11
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: The expected result is completely unclear. How are the `x` values from `b` related or joined to the `name` values from `a`? Or do you simply want a one-row answer with the first `name` and the sum of all `x`’s? Please show two small tables as example input and the expected output table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  a.name,
  b.sumx
from
  (select name from a where rownum <=1) a,
  (select sum(x) as sumx from b) b
;
```